# Fill a JS snippet with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

How can I input results of a PHP array inside a JS-file?

I have this PHP-snippet which returns an Array:

```
$activiteiten = Project::getProjectnames($_DB);
if(!empty($activiteiten)) {
    foreach($activiteiten as $k => $v) {
        $projectNames[] = $v['project'];
    }
}
```

How can I get these values inside this JS:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "Option 1",
            "Option 2",
            "Option 3",
            "Option 4"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the PHP array in stead of the `Option 1`, `Option 2`, `Option 3`,... But how do I do this?

I'm generating the JS by using a PHP `echo`-call.

Comment: Are you requesting the page from JavaScript (Ajax), or are you generating the JavaScript with PHP?

Comment: I'm generating the JS with PHP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($projectNames); ?>;
```

Comment: Thats nice and clean, I only suggested a way closest to the orginal code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            <?php 
                foreach($activiteiten as $k => $v){
                       echo '"'.$v['project'].'",';
                }
             ?>
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's nice. But how can I use it when generating the JS with PHP?

Comment: There are several ways, and these are not the most beautiful ones, but you could have your php logic, then close php tags and put this the above code in:

eg: <?php  //code here ?>  JS here <?php // activiteiten loop here ?> some more JS <?php //end of PHP logic ?>.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I think I'll do it like Ignacio said. It's more compressed :-)

Comment: Yeah I agree, as I said, I just wanted to stay close to your code :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is [json encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) that array and echo it in the context of javascript; thus setting a variable equal to it. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var availableTags = <?php echo(json_encode($myArray)); ?>
</script>
```